# Search database using Entity Framework. LIKE operator

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, search

I want to search one of my tables using Entity Framework 5. I don't know how many words there are in the query, but I want to match all of them.

query = *hello*

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] LIKE '%hello%'
```

query = *hello world*

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] LIKE '%hello%' AND [column] LIKE '%world%'
```

I know the function [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) , but it doesn't work good enough. Why? I'll show you:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE PATINDEX('%test%.com%', email)>0
```

will match "test@email.com", but if the search word are ordered the other way, it will not find this person:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE PATINDEX('%.com%test%', email)>0
```

What is the most efficient way to create this query using EF?

Answer (score 1):

using linq to entities you can use .Contains to do the equivilant in SQL

```
 table(x => x.column).Where(y => y.ColumnName).Contains("hello");
```

Sorry forgot the where clause that should work.

Comment: this will generate "select * from table where column LIKE 'hello'". if you add % in your contains it will generate (( CAST(CHARINDEX(N'%' + @p__linq__1 + N'%', [Extent1].[column]) AS int)) > 0)

Comment: @stian.net Why would you add `%`?

Comment: @Bob because I want to search.. LIKE 'test' will not return columns containing 'test'

Comment: You don't need to add %.  Entity framework will surround your string with % for you.  For example, Contains("hello") will turn into LIKE N'%hello%' in Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query in a `foreach` loop:

```cs
var words = new[] {"com", "test"};
var table = <your initial DbSet or ObjectSet>

foreach (var word in words)
{
    string word1 = word; // prevent modified closure.
    table = table.Where(x => x.column.Contains(word1));
}

var result = table.ToList(); // Enumerate the composed linq query.
```

The `Contains` function translates to `LIKE` with the search term enclosed in `%` characters.